# ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH with tomcat7 and node.js server java8 godaddy certificate

Tags: node.js, https, ssl-certificate, keytool

I am getting ERR_SSL_VERSION_OR_CIPHER_MISMATCH after using the certificate i obtained from GoDaddy. I converted the crt to jks and using it in tomcat.

nmap --script ssl-enum-ciphers.nse -p443 site.com

TLSv1.0: No supported ciphers found
|   TLSv1.1: No supported ciphers found
|_  TLSv1.2: No supported ciphers found

using tomcat7

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It was a problem with the jks file.

Since my requirement was to create a private key file to use in Node.js server and a tomcat keystore simultaneously. None of the solutions were giving me how to do it. It will explain either about creating a CSR for Node.js server or for tomcat only.

I finally found solution in

https://confluence.atlassian.com/kb/how-to-import-an-existing-ssl-certificate-for-use-in-tomcat-838412853.html

which created the keystore using the private key and the certificate.

For those who are having similar issue follow the below steps.

1) create the csr and private key using openssl.
2) Upload the csr with any certificate signing authority
3) Obtain the certificates. root ,intermediate and domain certificates.
4) Use the commands given in the link to generate the keystore and import it.
5) Use it in your tomcat configuration file.
6) Use the private key and the domain certificate in your Node.js server.

If anyone having issues please reply here will be happy to help.